# My Alt-Tab is looking different

Tags: alt-tab

I am not sure why but my Alt Tab is looking like some legacy version. I use windows 10 pro. I have never seen this happen before.

[image: A screen snip]

Comment: Possibly your ALT keys are stuck or faulty. You can cause this behaviour if you press and hold the right Alt key, press and release the left Alt key, and press Tab to have Alt+Tab show open windows as classic icons instead. Or you (or someboidy else) have/has set it as default by changing a registry key as described [here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/99205-set-alt-tab-use-classic-icons-thumbnails-windows.html) or you have run some 'tweaker' app.

Comment: Check the settings in Settings, System, Multitasking.  Look at the Alt-Tab pull down and set it as you need. See if that helps.

Comment: Thank you Michael Harvey  I am used to the registry editor so I did it easily,